# How to sort an array with numbers and text (TypeScript/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am very new to TypeScript and Javascript. I am trying to sort an array that contains both numbers and strings e.g. (1, 5, 27.5, Other, Mobile). I want it to display the numbers ascending first and then text after in alphabetically order. I tried

```
myarr.sort (function (a, b) {
            return (a-b);
}
```

I get an error saying the operator '-' cannot be applied to types string and string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to handle browsers lower than IE9, [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is a good choice.

Get the numbers and sort them:

```
var nums = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return typeof el === 'number';
}).sort();
```

Get the strings and sort them:

```
var strings = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return typeof el === 'string';
}).sort();
```

Concatonate the two arrays:

```
var result = nums.concat(strings);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PYLaX/3/).

Comment: You can use _.filter to get the same behaviour in older browsers